# Does .NET have any library for getting SQL server operators as strings?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, t-sql

I'm writing some dynamic SQL in my C# code and I don't want to hard-code stuff like `"OR"` and `"AND"`. So I'm wondering if .NET has some helper class that has an enum for the string representation of T-SQL operators.

Comment: I don't see the point. The keywords "Or" and "And" aren't going to change.  Also why an `enum`?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not anything like this in .NET. However, T-SQL changes about as fast as mud. Why not just create your own enumeration. I am sure it will be maintainable.

Comment: If you went though [the source code of Entity Framework](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6) I bet you could find a lot of that work done already.